# How to use two joins on the same column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables : one table it matchs and the other is teams. In matches, I have a date, the time and two IDs (the two teams). In teams I have an ID and the name of the team. What I want to do is get the list of matchs with the names of the teams. 
I know the INNER JOIN can do this but I'm not sure how ... here's what I have :

```
SELECT teams.name AS team1, teams.name AS team2, matchs.id, matchs.date, matchs.time
FROM matchs
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id=matchs.team1
```

Obviously, all I get is the name of the team1. How can I have both team names?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like below. Just use aliases to differentiate the two joins and make your code more expressive.

```
SELECT teams1.name AS team1, teams2.name AS team2, matchs.id, matchs.date, matchs.time
FROM matchs
    INNER JOIN teams AS teams1
        ON teams1.id=matchs.team1
    INNER JOIN teams AS teams2 
        ON teTeams2ams.id=matchs.team2
```

Comment: Seems like my SQL classes are pretty far! That was just it, it works great, thank you!

Comment: Yah, aliases are very useful here. I made the original join alias as teams1 so that it is more clear which is teams1 and which is teams2, also.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to perform two joins:

```
SELECT t1.name AS team1, t2.name AS team2, 
       matchs.id, matchs.date, matchs.time
FROM matchs
    INNER JOIN teams t1 
        ON t1.id = matchs.team1  
    INNER JOIN teams t2 
        ON t2.id = matchs.team2
```

The tables are [aliased](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) (`t1`, `t2`) to differentiate between each dataset in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.name AS team1, t2.name AS team2, matchs.id, matchs.date, matchs.time
FROM matchs
INNER JOIN teams t1 ON t1.id = matchs.team1 
INNER JOIN teams t2 on t2.id = matchs.team2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing another join and giving the table aliases:

```
SELECT t1.name AS team1, t2.name AS team2, matchs.id, matchs.date, matchs.time
FROM matchs
INNER JOIN teams as t1 ON t1.id = matchs.team1
INNER JOIN teams ON as t2 t2.id = matchs.team1
```